Linux Freezes for a second on USB Hub load
Backstory, whenever I switch TO my Ubuntu desktop on my kvm, Gnome appears to have a few second freeze issue. I can move the mouse and type and audio keeps playing, but videos will pause (audio is still playing and video skips) across all sources (Firefox, Chrome, VLC). Window inputs also freeze (I can click into a text box and type but that text won't appear for a few seconds then vomits all out at once). Then everything goes back to normal.
I have a cheap tcnewcl 4 port 4k KVM switch. I don't think it's directly the issue but rather how it interacts with the USB loading process in Ubuntu and specifically the usb driver loading process through my KVM. This is a guess though.
If it's worth noting, when I switch away from my Ubuntu desktop, everything works as expected. Videos keep playing on my second monitor (plugged in direct) fine and nothing freezes.
This happens across multiple Ubuntu hosts and I've also tried Rasbperry Pi's to test this and bingo, has the same issue.
dmesg:
[64448.714661] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 20
[64448.714665] usb 1-6.1: USB disconnect, device number 21
[64448.964430] usb 1-6.2: USB disconnect, device number 22
[64451.639261] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
[64451.795434] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=1a40, idProduct=0801, bcdDevice= 1.00
[64451.795438] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[64451.795439] usb 1-6: Product: USB 2.0 Hub
[64451.796115] hub 1-6:1.0: USB hub found
[64451.796169] hub 1-6:1.0: 4 ports detected
[64452.095265] usb 1-6.1: new full-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
[64452.211454] usb 1-6.1: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=fc4d, bcdDevice= 1.52
[64452.211457] usb 1-6.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[64452.211459] usb 1-6.1: Product: USB Gaming Mouse
[64452.222022] input: USB Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.1/1-6.1:1.0/0003:04D9:FC4D.001F/input/input81
[64452.222160] hid-generic 0003:04D9:FC4D.001F: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.1/input0
[64452.224851] input: USB Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.1/1-6.1:1.1/0003:04D9:FC4D.0020/input/input82
[64452.283439] hid-generic 0003:04D9:FC4D.0020: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.1/input1
[64452.288640] input: USB Gaming Mouse Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.1/1-6.1:1.2/0003:04D9:FC4D.0021/input/input83
[64452.347372] input: USB Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.1/1-6.1:1.2/0003:04D9:FC4D.0021/input/input84
[64452.347459] hid-generic 0003:04D9:FC4D.0021: input,hiddev1,hidraw6: USB HID v1.10 Device [USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.1/input2
[64452.447260] usb 1-6.2: new low-speed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd
[64452.575847] usb 1-6.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=7603, bcdDevice= 1.17
[64452.575850] usb 1-6.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[64452.575852] usb 1-6.2: Product: USB Keyboard
[64452.583373] input: USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2:1.0/0003:0C45:7603.0022/input/input85
[64452.647585] hid-generic 0003:0C45:7603.0022: input,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2/input0
[64452.652892] input: USB Keyboard Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2:1.1/0003:0C45:7603.0023/input/input86
[64452.711537] input: USB Keyboard System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2:1.1/0003:0C45:7603.0023/input/input87
[64452.711777] input: USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.2/1-6.2:1.1/0003:0C45:7603.0023/input/input89
[64452.711978] hid-generic 0003:0C45:7603.0023: input,hiddev2,hidraw8: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6.2/input1
[64459.292647] kauditd_printk_skb: 452 callbacks suppressed

I think that the issue is the USB 2.0 Hub itself, where when loading for some reason these systems take a moment to load and this is what I'm experiencing. I'm wondering if there's either a way to keep this device loaded so it doesn't do this, or some solution to make this more fluid to switch on my kvm.
Any suggestions are appreciated!

I do not see an actual question here. I do see there is no mention of a version of Ubuntu. From the info that you have posted I do not see anything in any OS that needs to be fixed. An inexpensive KVM device is the most likely cause.

No, the cause is the drivers being loaded for said USB hub. You can see that in the dmesg output. As for version, as I stated this is happening on ubuntu independent of version (20.04, 22.04, 24.04 all tested and showed the same behavior), and multiple versions of Raspberry Pi's all showed the same behavor.
I'm sure this is an issue with the drivers and not the hub or ubuntu directly. But as for my question, specifically I asked "I'm wondering if there's either a way to keep this device loaded so it doesn't do this, or some solution to make this more fluid to switch on my kvm."

As a note of interest, I have tested plugging in the hub with and without other devices attached to it (keyboard and mouse) and it's deff the hub drivers causing this. However, when I plug in the hub and then plug in the mouse/keyboard it also shows the same behavior for mouse and keyboard loading through the hub. This doesn't happen when I plug in the mouse/keyboard directly.

It may also be that the issue is actually something interrupting the system during detection on the hub. If that's the case it's deff a linux kernel issue because even if the hub is damaged or inoperable it shouldn't interrupt the system.

Please do not add info for the question with comments. They do not always get read and go away in time. Edit the question and add the info. I know I wont read all these super long comments.

maybe I was a bit more specific, but I was really just copy/pasting my question in there for you since you didn't see it.
